# Unrecognized name: size_bytes - Google Cloud Platform

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, size

I'm trying to find the size in bytes/MB for each base table in a dataset on Google Cloud Platform using the following SQL code:

-- Returns metadata for tables in a single dataset.

```
SELECT 
table_name,
table_type,
sum(size_bytes)/pow(10,9) as size
FROM [PROJECT].[PROJECT NODE].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

However GCP gives me the error message "Unrecognized name: size_bytes  - Google Cloud Platform".

Does anyone know of a way to do this?
Also, does anyone know of a site that shows alternatives to standard SQL functions for GCP?

Thanks for your help,

Matt

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Hi Jarlh - can you clarify please? If I add a GROUP BY clause at the end (using table_name) it is still giving me Unrecognized name: size_bytes at [4:5]

Answer (score 0):

Through some more googling I think I've found the answer to my own question. The following gave me the name of each table, the number of rows in it, as well as the size in bytes:

```
SELECT table_id, row_count, size_bytes
FROM `[PROJECT].[PROJECT NODE].__TABLES__`
ORDER BY table_id DESC
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).